# delete a node in xml using linq to xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to remove a node from a xml file using value of an element

Here is my xml

```
 <Employee>
  <User>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Username>John</Username>
    <Lastname>Smith</Lastname>
  </User>
<User>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Username>jerry</Username>
    <Lastname>wilson</Lastname>
  </User>
</Employee>
```

And here is my code behind

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/User.xml"));
            doc.Elements("User")
           .Elements("ID")
           .Where(l => l.Value == textbox1.text)
           .Select(x => x.Parent)
           .Remove();
```

i want to remove the `<user>` node whose `<id>` is entered in textbox
but its not working.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `doc.Root` property or `doc.Descendants("User")` to return filtered collection of the descendant elements :

1.

```
doc.Root.Elements("User")
           .Elements("ID")
           .Where(l => l.Value == textbox1.text)
           .Select(x => x.Parent)
           .Remove();
```

2.

```
 doc.Root.Elements("User")
            .Where(p => p.Element("ID").Value == textbox1.text)
            .Remove();
 doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~/User.xml"));
```